# I have a trouble in define my own Find function

Tags: recursion

Here is my code, I try to do recursion to make a list of position but it return None or Error. I tried to fixed it by adding index but when it is recursive, it have Error: positional argument follows keyword argument.

```
def myfind(text,key,start=0, index=None):
  if index is None:
    index=[]  
  else:
    i=0
    j=start
    check=0
    while i<len(key) and j<len(text):
      if key[i]==text[j]:
        i+=1
        j+=1
        check+=1
      else:
        i=0
        j+=1
        check=0
    if check==len(key):
    # print(j-len(key),'->',j-1,sep='')
      index.append(j-len(key))
      myfind(text,key,start=j, index)
    if j==len(text) and len(index)>0:
      return {'index':index,'check':True}
    else:
      # print('not found')
      return {'check':False}
s='i love you so, so you can love me, whenever you want so'
print(myfind(s,'so'))
```

Comment: What must be shown after the execution of the recursive function?

Comment: It should return a list of the index of the substr. btw i find a way without recursion needed  but thank you so